# fancy-preview perl script will not extract tables

Tags: fancytooltips

```
% call pdflatex example.tex and everything works fine.
% call perl fancy-preview.pl example.tex and no tables will be separated. remove tables and everyhing works fine. 

\listfiles
\tracingstats=2
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,twoside=false,captions=tableheading,hyperref]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
% \usepackage{varioref}
% --ini_file=inifile.ini
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}\\ \hline
0 & 3 & 3 & 2\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A}
\label{tab:A}
\end{table}

\ref{tab:A}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:E}
(r(t)|x'|^{p-2}x')'+c(t)|x|^{p-2}x+\sum_{i=1}^m c_i(t)|x|^{p_i-2}x=e(t),
\end{equation}
\ref{eq:E}


\end{document}
```

There will be added to more questions in a separate thread. (how to add varioref and how to use tooltipanim with a still existing file of fancytooltip)

I cannot understand, why table cannot be extracted.

Answer (score 1):

Take the following code and save as info.ini

```
[main]
pdfcrop=pdfcrop

[latex]
environments=theorem,remark,minipage,hoare
snarfenvironments=

a_extra=\AtBeginDocument{\def\punctation#1{}}

b_extra=\AtBeginDocument{\newgeometry{textwidth=4.2in}}

tooltips_envelope_preamble=\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}\def\tooltipwraper#1{\begin{tikzpicture}\node[shading=axis,bottom color=yellow!5,top color=yellow!40,shading angle=-45,draw=black!80, rounded corners=10pt,very thick]{{\fboxsep 6pt \fboxrule 0 pt \fbox{#1}}};\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Take the followinc code:

```
% call pdflatex example.tex and everything works fine.
% call perl fancy-preview.pl example.tex and no tables will be separated. remove tables and everyhing works fine. 

\listfiles
\tracingstats=2
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,twoside=false,captions=tableheading,hyperref]{scrreprt}
\def\punctation#1{#1}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}\centering
   \mbox{\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}\centering
          \begin{tabular}{c c c c}\\ \hline
            0 & 3 & 3 & 2\\ \hline
          \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}}
    \caption{Tabelle 1}\label{tab:meinetabelle}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\ref{tab:meinetabelle}



\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:E}
(r(t)|x'|^{p-2}x')'+c(t)|x|^{p-2}x+\sum_{i=1}^m c_i(t)|x|^{p_i-2}x=e(t),
\end{equation}
\ref{eq:E}


\end{document}
```

compile with pdflatex example.tex and perl fancy-preview.pl example -ini_file=info.ini

Should work as expected under windows...